# datagrid sorting is being undone each time itemsource receives an update

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DataGrid in a WPF application that binds an ItemSource. Every three seconds when this ItemSource receives an update the sorting on the DataGrid gets thrown out of whack. It is as close to a live feed I can get from our call system so the update every three seconds is needed. Question is how do I get the sorting to stay and or reapply before the update hits the DataGrid so the user does not see it sorted incorrectly. I've posted some code below but have no idea what information you may need to help resolve this. I've been fighting with it all day.

GOAL: Currently the code programmically sorts this list. It works for three seconds as stated above but sorting it programmically is not the goal. I'm here because I need help figuring out why it doesn't stay sorted on the data grid. I want the users to be able to sort it anyway they want in the long run. I need the sort to stop going away each time the item source is updated.

Code Behind:

```
private void textBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FeedServiceAgent data = new FeedServiceAgent();

            data.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
            data.Subscribe("92", 3);
        }

        private void OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                List<NewAgent> newAgentList = new List<NewAgent>();
                if (e == null)
                    return;

                if (e.CmsData != null)
                {


                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
                    {                                         
                        foreach (var item in e.CmsData.Agents)
                        {
                            NewAgent newAgents = new ScoreBoardClientTest.NewAgent();

                            newAgents.AgentName = item.AgName;

                            newAgents.AgentExtension = item.Extension;

                            newAgents.AgentDateTimeChange = ConvertedDateTimeUpdated;

                            newAgents.AuxReasons = item.AuxReasonDescription;

                            newAgents.LoginIdentifier = item.LoginId;

                            newAgents.AgentState = item.WorkModeDirectionDescription;

                            var timeSpanSince = DateTime.Now - item.DateTimeUpdated;
                            newAgents.AgentDateTimeStateChange = timeSpanSince;   

                            newAgentList.Add(newAgents);

                            ListCollectionView myListCollectionView = new ListCollectionView(newAgentList);

                            myListCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("AgentState", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
                            myListCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("AuxReasons", ListSortDirection.Descending));
                            myListCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("AgentDateTimeStateChange", ListSortDirection.Descending));

                            DataGrid.ItemsSource = myListCollectionView;
                        }                                                                   
                    }));                    
                }
            }
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ColumnWidth="*"  Foreground="Green" FontSize="10"   Loaded="textBlock_Loaded" Margin="0,10" RenderTransformOrigin="0.127,0.275" Background="{x:Null}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding AgentName}"  />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="State" Binding="{Binding AgentState}"  />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Aux" Binding="{Binding AuxReasons}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Binding="{Binding AgentDateTimeStateChange, StringFormat={}{0:hh}:{0:mm}:{0:ss}}"/>                                          
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

CS for List Objects:

```
class NewAgent
    {
        public string AgentName { get; set; }
        public int AgentExtension { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan AgentDateTimeChange { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan AgentDateTimeStateChange { get; set; }
        public String AuxReasons { get; set; }
        public string LoginIdentifier { get; set; }
        public string AgentState { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution (not elegant but should work) - save `dataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions` before setting new ItemSource.

Remove lines in your code where you doing `myListCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add` and try following

```
var sorting = DataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions
       .Select(x => new {x.PropertyName, x.Direction}).ToList();

DataGrid.ItemsSource = myListCollectionView;

foreach (var item in sorting)
{
   var col = DataGrid.Columns
               .First(x => x.SortMemberPath == item.PropertyName);
   col.SortDirection = item.Direction;
   DataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(
         new SortDescription(item.PropertyName, item.Direction));
 };
```

Comment: I updated the question. your code will not compile but it doesn't matter because in the long run unfortunately it doesn't solve the big problem of how do you keep the data grid from unsorting it self when it receives an update. sorry :/

Comment: @mcavanaugh418 I fixed my code and now it should work. Can you try it?

Comment: so the code compiled and the program runs without errors but it has 0 effect on the sorting.

Comment: @mcavanaugh418 I created simple example [here](https://gist.github.com/Benzeliden/b83cbb46043648b9f32e138be6bd629b) and it's work for me - when you choose any sorting it doesn't reset

Comment: so something weird happened. last night when I originally tested this it had no effect on the application. this morning I opened it before even coming here and it functioned properly. I know that doesn't make sense and is impossible technically, maybe I just wasn't paying attention or it didn't build right. either way your solution did fix this major issue for me and I appreciate it. marking your answer as the correct one. have a great day and thanks again for your help!